# React Native / React navigation, same level component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have 2 classes: my default class *HomeScreen* used for the home page and another class *MyList* which I use to generate a flatlist on my *HomeScreen*.
My problem is that I do not succeed in building my navigation function in my *MyList* class.

I always get the following error: "Can't find variable: navigate".

I took a look at this [Calling Navigate on Top Level Component](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/docs/api/navigators/Navigators.md) but I really don't know how to implement it in my code.

**Here's what I've tried:**

```
class MyList extends React.Component {

    _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.note.id;

    _renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <TouchableNativeFeedback
            onPress={() => navigate('Note', { noteId: item.note.id })} >
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.noteElementTitle} >{item.note.title}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.noteElementBody} >{item.note.body}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableNativeFeedback>
    );

    render() {
        return (
            <FlatList
                data={this.props.data}
                keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
                renderItem={this._renderItem}
            />
        );
    }

}


export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Notes',
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 187, 0)' },
        headerTitleStyle: { color: 'white' },
    };

    render() {

        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

        return (
                <MyList
                    data={this.state.data}
                    load={this.state.load}
                    navig={this.props.navigation}
                >
                </MyList>

        );
    }
}

const Project = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    NewNote: { screen: NewNoteScreen },
    Note: { screen: NoteScreen }
});


AppRegistry.registerComponent('Project', () => Project);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `MyList` component is not part of your stack the navigation prop is not available for that.

You have 2 options.

First option you can pass the navigation prop manually to MyList

```
render() {
  const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
  return (
    <MyList
      data={this.state.data}
      load={this.state.load}
      navigation={this.props.navigation}
    >
    </MyList>
  );
}
```

Second option you can use [`withNavigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/views/with-navigation).

> `withNavigation` is a Higher Order Component which passes the navigation
>   prop into a wrapped Component. It's useful when you cannot pass the
>   navigation prop into the component directly, or don't want to pass it
>   in case of a deeply nested child.

```
import { Button } 'react-native';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

const MyComponent = ({ to, navigation }) => (
    <Button title={`navigate to ${to}`} onPress={() => navigation.navigate(to)} />
);

const MyComponentWithNavigation = withNavigation(MyComponent);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. If I go with option 1, what should I add in my Flatlist to fetch the navigation prop ?

Comment: You don't need to do anything different. It will be available like the normal navigation prop. To use navigate you can again do `const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;`

Comment: It works if I do not use my _renderItem function but instead directly write my render function in the flatlist block. Thanks a lot bennygenel !