# undefined is not an object react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I am not having any idea why i am getting

> "undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   '_this.props.navigation.navigate')"

I am new bie in react but i have gone through each possible solution but still getting this err. I am sharing my code below:

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Login from './app/components/Login/Login';
import Dashboard from './app/components/Dashboard/Dashboard';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

const Application = StackNavigator({
        Home: { screen: Login },
        Dashboard: { screen: Dashboard },
    }, {
        navigationOptions: {
            header: false
        }
});

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Application />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

**Login.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Image, Text, TextInput, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

export default class Login extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding' style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
                    <Image source={require('../../images/logo.png')}
                           style={styles.logo}
                    />
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Share Emotions Instantly..</Text>
                <View style={styles.formContainer}>
                    <LoginForm></LoginForm>
                </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#bdc3c7',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },

    logoContainer: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },

    logo: {
        width: 70,
        height: 70
    }
});
```

**LoginForm.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Text, Alert } from 'react-native';
import Dashboard from '../Dashboard/Dashboard';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

export default class LoginForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    onButtonPress = () => {
        alert('ok');
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        navigate('Dashboard');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput underlineColorAndroid="transparent" 
                           style={styles.input} 
                           placeholder="username or email" 
                           placeholderTextColor='rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'
                           returnKeyType="next"
                           keyboardType="email-address"
                           autoCapitalize="none"
                           autoCorrect={false}
                           onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordInput.focus()}>
                </TextInput>

                <TextInput underlineColorAndroid="transparent" 
                           style={styles.input} 
                           placeholder="password" 
                           placeholderTextColor='rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'
                           returnKeyType='go'
                           ref={(input) => this.passwordInput = input}
                           secureTextEntry> 
                </TextInput>

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}
                                  onPress={this.onButtonPress}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: 20
    },

    input: {
        height: 40,
        marginBottom: 15,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)',
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        width: 300
    },

    buttonContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#888',
        paddingVertical: 10
    },

    buttonText: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#fff',
        fontWeight: '700'
    }
});
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

export default class Dashboard extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>this is Dashboard</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1
    }
});
```

I know this is a common issue, but I'm still not getting why 'navigation' object has not passed through as props to the other components.

Comment: I can't see where you are trying to pass down `navigation` as a prop anywhere?

Comment: I'm new to react myself, but I think you need to pass the property when you create the LoginForm element in the Login component. <LoginForm pass the property here></LoginForm>

Comment: @Leth I dont have anything to pass. just want to navigate to dashboard page when click button for now. and if i still need to do so can u pls tell me which property to pass and how??

Comment: I went through tutorial which has no passing but tutorial is working. do i really need to pass anything ?@Chris

Comment: in _login.js_ `<LoginForm></LoginForm>` you should pass a prop named `navigation`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native / React navigation, same level component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46533148/react-native-react-navigation-same-level-component)

Comment: Many Many thanks @bennygenel worked like charm !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation property will be injected into all screens that you add to the route configs for ScreenNavigator (in your case Home and Dashboard).  However, for child components of those screens you will have to pass down the navigation property.

`<LoginForm navigation={this.props.navigation} />`

Comment: I see !! that's the case. thanks for ur reply and description. can you please answer me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671198/how-to-generate-apk-or-ios-file-of-react-native-project

Comment: I didn’t see enough advantages to expo to bother with using it. The answers already on the post seem fair