# how to generate apk or ios file of React Native project

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am building a RN project with "create-react-native-app" and "Expo". So how it is possible to run on Android & Ios device? How i can generate APK file? I am using sublime text 3 for writing code.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind opening your app through the Expo app on real devices, all you need is to publish it onto the Expo ecosystem. [Read more about publishing.](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/publishing.html#how-to-publish)

If you do mind that extra step and want to go the normal way, you need to create a standalone app for distribution:

> When you’re ready to distribute your app to end-users, you can create
>   a standalone app binary (an ipa or apk file) and put it in the iOS App
>   Store and the Google Play Store. [See the full guide to building a
>   standalone app.](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/building-standalone-apps.html)

[Source](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/publishing.html#deploying-to-the-app-store-and-play-store)

Comment: Nice !! so after building the project, edit app.json file for 'exp' configuration and then need to build the apk?? @designorant

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your question but if you follow the full guide link that I quoted above they'll guide you through everything, including the update and possible rebuild processes (see point 7). The rule is that rebuilding isn't really necessary if you don't touch `app.json`. Expo does quite a lot of things behind the scenes for you. Their docs are superb so I highly recommend going through them all.

Comment: ok thanks a lot man. actually i just wanted to make sure as i am using expo whether i can generate apk and ipa file without any coding after finishing my project.